# Trouble with Cordova NFC plugin: nfc has no method 'connect'

Tags: android, cordova, nfc

My Cordova app (for Android, using phonegap-nfc plugin) successfully receives an NFC intent and displays the UID of the tag, but the `onConnected` method isn't called.

This is my index.js file:

```
var app = {
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
                app.onNfc,
                function () { },
                function (reason) { app.showText("Ups: " + reason); }
              );
        },
        onNfc: function (nfcEvent) {      
          var tag = nfcEvent.tag;
          app.showText(JSON.stringify(nfcEvent.tag));
          var nfcUid = nfc.bytesToHexString(tag.id);
          app.showText(' nfcEvent.tag = ' + nfcUid);
          nfc.connect(
            app.onConnected, // chipcard connected
            function ()       { app.showText('connection successful'); },
            function (reason) { app.showText('connect failed: ' + reason); }
          );    
        },
        onConnected: function () {
            app.showText('onConnected');
            nfc.transceive(
                "00A400",       // RequestAPDU
                function (data) { // ResponseAPDU
                   app.showText("transceive successful: " + data);
                },
                function (reason) {
                   app.showText("transceive failed: " + reason);
                }
            );
            nfc.close(
               app.onConnected, // remove hander
               function ()       { app.showTxt('close successful'); },
               function (reason) { app.showTxt('close failed: ' + reason); }
            );
        },
        receivedEvent: function(id) {
            var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

            console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        },  
        showText: function(message) {
            var label = document.createTextNode(message),
                lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
            messageDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);         // add a line break
            messageDiv.appendChild(label);             // add the text  
        }
    };

    app.initialize();
```

I noticed the following error in the logs:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'connect'", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (48)

It means that `nfc` has no method `connect()`. Why? There's a description of this method in the docs: https://github.com/jalbersol/phonegap-nfc#nfcconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a different version of the phonegap-nfc plugin. The standard phonegap-nfc plugin (from Chariot Solutions, you can get it here https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) does **not** support the ISO-DEP communication methods (connect/disconnect/transeive). You need use that modified version of the plugin from https://github.com/jalbersol/phonegap-nfc if you want to use these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue. It was really due to the wrong version of the plugin. To install correct plugin you need to add to path in EV "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" and "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" (of course, before that Git must be installed). Then you can add correct plugin with the following command:

> $ cordova plugin add https://github.com/jalbersol/phonegap-nfc.git

It helped me and now onConnected method is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for adding some further info on how to add that specific version of the plugin!